# How do I properly convert List to ArrayList of my type of Object?

Tags: java, arraylist, casting, jdbctemplate

I have a `JdbcTemplate` query that fetches all the records from the database table using `queryForList`. I have a class that operates on `ArrayList`s mainly and would like to convert the List to `ArrayList<Customer>`. In the debugger it retrieves the records fine, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to cast the `Object` to a `Customer` and create an `ArrayList` of type `Customer`. Here is my code:

```
public static ArrayList<Customer> getCustomers(){
        String query = "SELECT customerId,lastName,firstName,email,address,city,state,zip FROM " +
                "Customers";
        List customerList = jdbcTemplate.queryForList(query);
        ArrayList<Customer> customerArrayList = new ArrayList(customerList);
        return customerArrayList;
    }
```

Comment: What does `queryForList()` look like? Could you provide more code?

Comment: Is there any reason that your _"class that operates on ArrayLists"_ has to operate only on ArrayLists?  Why would it not work on any arbitrary kind of `List<>`?  That is to say, rather than try to force an ArrayList from `queryForList`, make your other class work on any list implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is there any reason `List` is naked instead of `List<Customer>`? I believe that's all you need to fix.

Note `ArrayList` supports the constructor

```
ArrayList(Collection<? extends E> c)
```

Which you are trying to use.

From [Spring's JDBC Template documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.0.M1/api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html) it looks like you need to "hint" the return type:

```
<T> List<T> queryForList(String sql, Class<T> elementType)
```

i.e. call

```
List<Customer> customerList = jdbcTemplate.queryForList(query, Customer.class);
```

Comment: If I change List to List<Customer> I get incompatible types

Comment: Thanks I will give it a go. I'm getting a different error now for incorrect column count expected: 1 actual 8.

Comment: Yes I think it's probably something unrelated but I think your solution is correct. Thanks!